# Adding data from one XML file to another - PHP

Tags: php, xml, xslt, scripting

Any help would be appreciated on this. Im looking to take a value from one XML file and input it into another XML using PHP preferably. I will accept any other methods of transformation if they work.

**XML 1**

```
<field-list>
<field Id="spMF_1_1634">
    <tag>Customer Name</tag>
    <type>string</type>
    <required>true</required>
    <value>1Test</value>
</field>
<field Id="spMF_2_1634">
    <tag>Job Reference</tag>
    <type>string</type>
    <required>false</required>
    <value>42442</value>
</field>
```

**XML 2**

```
<Log>
  <DataSource>Data_source</DataSource>
  <SQLStatement>SELECT TotalPrice FROM vwQuotations WHERE reference = 'REF42442'</SQLStatement>
  <SQLStatementResult>Success</SQLStatementResult>
  <SQLStatementValue>
    <Row>
      <Column Name="TotalPrice" DataType="REAL">2000</Column>
    </Row>
  </SQLStatementValue>
</Log>
```

**OUTPUT / RESULT IM LOOKING FOR:**

```
<field-list>
<field Id="spMF_1_1634">
    <tag>Customer Name</tag>
    <type>string</type>
    <required>true</required>
    <value>1Test</value>
</field>
<field Id="spMF_2_1634">
    <tag>Job Reference</tag>
    <type>string</type>
    <required>false</required>
    <value>42442</value>
</field>
<field Id="AnyID">
    <tag>TotalPrice</tag>
    <type>string</type>
    <required>false</required>
    <value>2000</value>
</field>
```

The Value of the third field (2000) is really what i require added to the first XML.

As you can see the two XML are in different formats.
I hope I have explained myself clearly.

To summarise I'm looking to add an extra field to XML 1 with the child properties to match 2000 from XML 2 and output in the same format as XML 1 as per my output example.

Thank you.

******EDIT******

I'm using automation software to handle these files so unfortunately I'm unable to pass parameters to the XML.

I'm striping XML off a PDF (XML 1) and I can pass it through a XSLT transform module to export to a CSV.

XML 2 is pulled from a database and can be held in a static folder.

Please see below screenshot with annotations.

Can I hardcode the XML 2 File path into the XLT Transform to insert the data?

[image]

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) php code. What did you already try ? It will be easier for us to help you.

Comment: Hi Alexandre, apologies, I can't create php code for you as I'm not fluent in PHP. I have just edited php code in the past to perform such tasks and I know I can utilise it with the software I'm using as per my edit. I have tried various "in software" attempts to perform this task however they aren't worth mentioning here. michael.hor257k below is very close with his XSLT however I'm having trouble with it pulling the value from XML2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell your processor to process the first XML and pass the path to the second XML as a parameter. Then use a stylesheet like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="path-to-file2"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="field-list">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <field Id="AnyID">
            <tag>TotalPrice</tag>
            <type>string</type>
            <required>false</required>
            <value>
                <xsl:value-of select="document($path-to-file2)/Log/SQLStatementValue/Row/Column"/>
            </value>
        </field>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for your response. This looks very promising, however the only obstacle I have is that I cant pass parameters to the XSL. I have added an edit to my post to explain. Would it be possible to hardcode the XML2 path?

Comment: I have tried your formula and have received some results. The XSLT adds the fields to the XML1 file however it is not adding the value and seems to be missing the opening tag for it. Im presuming this is because I have tried to hardcode the XML2 file path. Would you be able to source where I'm going wrong?

MY EDIT TO YOUR CODE:
<xsl:param name="path-to-file2" value="Macintosh HD/Users/universalgraphics/Desktop/CSV/XML Merge/42442.xml"/>

RESULT ADDED TO XML1:
<field Id="AnyID">
   <tag>TotalPrice</tag>
   <type>string</type>
   <required>false</required>
   <value/>
  </field>

Comment: Yes, the path can be hard-coded. However, the path is a string, it needs to be quoted. Or - preferably - use it as literal text: `<xsl:param name="path-to-file2">/Users/universalgraphics/Desktop/CSV/XML Merge/42442.xml</xsl:param>`.

Comment: Note that the path can be absolute or relative to the stylesheet (or to the XML source, if you so specify).

Comment: I have tried this however i seem to still get the same result and I cant figure it out. Here is what I'm getting in my output XML.

  <field Id="AnyID">
    <tag>TotalPrice</tag>
    <type>string</type>
    <required>false</required>
    <value/>
  </field>

Sorry I cant seem to figure out how to format it here but it is only outputting the close of the <value> field.

Comment: The exact absolute path may depend on your environment. It's difficult to troubleshoot without access to error messages. On my system, it works if the path starts with `/Users/` and the location steps are percent-encoded - i.e. `XM‌​L%20Merge` instead of `XM‌​L Merge`.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have no method of debugging or returning error messages. I have removed the space in the folder name to remove this from the equation. I have also tried referencing it relative from the stylesheet too as it is just one folder up.
`<xsl:param name="path-to-file2">//XM‌​LMerge/42442.xml</xsl:param>`
I greatly appreciate your help on this. I find it odd that it is only displaying the close <value/> field when outputted. I have tried adding and removing extra open and close fields thinking it may be returning one from XML2 however it didn't work.

Comment: I would start by placing the file in the same folder where the stylesheet is, and using `<xsl:param name="path-to-file2">42442.xml</xsl:param>`. If that doesn't work, then the problem is not with the path. -- Not sure what "just one folder up" means.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. Im not sure why the path wont point to it but it works this way and thats what counts. What works, works. I can use this as a good starting point now. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Michael,I was wondering if you could help me one last time. I need to save out each XML2 with the Job Reference value as the XML file name in order for it to be accurate i.e. 42442.xml (as before). Is there a way to set the parameter "path-to-file2" to the <value> in XML1 where the <tag> = "Job Reference". Ive tried to use W3 but Im just not good enough with XML.
So thats `<xsl:param name="path-to-file2"/>` = the <value> in `<field Id="spMF_2_1634">
    <tag>Job Reference</tag>
    <type>string</type>
    <required>false</required>
    <value>42442</value>
</field>`
      .xml

Comment: @James Code in comments is hard to read. IIUC, you want to have `<xsl:param name="path-to-file2" select="/field-list/field[tag='Job Reference']/@Id"/>`. Note that the supplied value has no file extension, so it may not be sufficient to point to the actual file.

Comment: Apologies, I probably didn't explain very well. I'm looking for it to make the "path-to-file2" the value of the child <value> where the value of the child <tag> is "Job Reference" and add the file extension .xml. So in my example of XML1 it will set the "path-to-file2" to 42442.xml.

Comment: Well, then use `<xsl:param name="path-to-file2" select="concat(/field-list/field[tag='Job Reference']/value, '.xml')"/>`.

Comment: Excellent, thank you, thats perfect. You are a life saver!